# Enterprise 1.13 Persistent Shopping cart with disabeld products

Tags: checkout, customer, products, shopping-cart, persistent

I have been having some issues where customers have added sale items to their basket. We have disabled the products and the customer can still purchase the products after they have been disabled if they are in their basket that has been saved using persistent shopping cart.

Is there a way of making sure that if the customer does checkout using this saved shopping cart products that have been disabled are either removed from the basket or a notice informs them that the item is no longer available

Comment: Not sure but I thought that when placing the order it would perform such a check by default.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I forgot to add a comment, we actually received a patch for this from Magento support as it was a bug in the core code at that time of asking